# VS 2012 RibbonButton Open Form

Tags: ribbon-control

How do you get a RibbonButton to open a Form (let's say Form1)? There is a click callback on RibbonButton called "Click" but I am not sure what to do with this. I am guessing something needs to go in the VB window but I have no idea what.

The MSDN library suggests "Event Click As RibbonControlEventHandler" which is great but what do you do with it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you put the code that shows in the form in the event handler. I don't understand your problem. Is it that you don't know how to show a form?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need an answer that involves some code for the XAML which begins <RibbonButton ... and then for the VB behind the form which will maybe begin with Event OnClick... I just want to be able to open a form that is called Form1. I have never used the WPF Ribbon before and I cannot find any useful material on the web to help me to learn it.

Comment: Google finds more detail - e.g. http://vb2010wpf.blogspot.co.uk/ for VS2010 or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/ for VS2012

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and you're right - it sucks - not at all intuitive. If I can figure it out, I'll post again ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just got a simple version working. It turned out that by default the button is only 4x4 pixels and you can't see it to click it - not sure if that was your problem too. Anyway, this is what I did ...

I had a main window with the Ribbon and RibbonButton - sized and coloured so I could see it

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin"  SelectedIndex="0">
            <RibbonButton x:Name="btnOne" Height="32" Width="32">
                <RibbonButton.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                </RibbonButton.Background>
            </RibbonButton>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then I added a second Window to be shown on the click event

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Finally, I added a Click handler for the RibbonButton on the main window

```
Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
    Dim wnd As Window1 = New Window1
    wnd.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Now everything works as expected. Does that help?

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. This worked perfectly. Your time is much appreciated. I have scoured forums and websites trying to find this simple code and I haven't been able to do so, until now.